# get unique color_id which stock's quantity is more than order's quantity

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get all color_id which product's stock(quantity) is available.

TABLE - stock

id | product_id | color_id | quantity

TABLE - order

id | client_id | stock_id | quantity

I want to get unique color_id from stock where stock's quantity is more than order's quantity and on particular product_id. if stock id doesn't exist in order table than order's quantity takes it as 0;

table order.stock_id is foreign key of table stock.id

I tried below query

SELECT * FROM stock s, order o where s.id = o.stock_id and (s.quantity-o.quantity)>0

if o.quantity doesn't exist it should take 0

Comment: Order is a reserve keyword you can't create a table with that name.Hope it is orders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to tell from the text what you are really asking.  But, if what you want is to treat "missing" orders as having `0` quantity, then you want a `left outer join`:

```
SELECT *
FROM stock s LEFT JOIN
     order o
     on s.id = o.stock_id
WHERE s.quantity > COALESCE(o.quantity, 0);
```

I'm not sure what this has to do with "color", but then your sample query has no mention of `color` either.

Comment: Left join would fetch all the rows from stock table regardless of the condition.

Comment: @user1613360 . . . And then the `where` clause is applied to filter the results.

Comment: What about the join condition?My guess is results where s.id<>o.stock_id and present in the stock table would be returned.Am I right?

Comment: @user1613360 . . . No.  `left outer join` returns all the rows in the first table along with matching rows in the second table (based on the `on` condition).  If there are no matches, then the row is returned from the first table with `NULL` values for the corresponding columns in the second table.

Comment: Ya. It's work now. I need COALESCE() function to replace zero if o.quantity doesn't exist. Thank you @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 0):

```
    select s.color_id from stock s
 where exists
(select * from order o where o.stock_id=s.id
 and s.quantity>o.quantity and s.product_id=123)
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. Tell where OP did go wrong in their approach. Tell in words what you did different. You can link documentation. Code-only answers are fairly useless to future visitors with similar problems.